# Задание констрейнтов

Tags: android

Внутри ConstraintLayout лежит AppBarLayout и FragmentContainerView. Хочу, чтобы FragmentContainerView отображался под AppBarLayout. Для этого для FragmentContainerView задаю

```xml
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
```

Но FragmentContainerView упорно растягивается на всю активити и залазит под ToolBar. В чем проблема?

Вот полный код макета

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.mycompany.DetectFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detect_list" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: так у вас в AppBarLayout стоит "app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/list"", попробуйте убрать и посмотреть что будет.

Comment: @ermak0ff Замечание правильное. Спасибо. IDE наставила. Заменил на `parent` ничего не изменилось

Comment: Попробуйте для `FragmentContainerView` задать `android:layout_height="0dp"` и нижний край привязать к паренту.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо. Было достаточно `android:layout_height="0dp"`. Объясните в ответе почему так?